# Xcode project that was generated by CMake is not show header file

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, header

I build my C++ project with CMake.
I want use Xcode as Editor
so, I run this command.

```
cmake . -GXcode
```

BTW, My C++ Project header and source file is located in different folder.

my project directory tree:

```
project_root
└CMakeLists.txt
└src
   └CMakeLists.txt
   └main.cpp
└include
   └xxx1.hpp
   └inner
      └in_xxx1.hpp
```

so I set src/CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
include_directories (
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
add_executable( "runrun" main.cpp )
```

In Xcode, only main.cpp file is shown.

[image]

I want see header file also in Xcode.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For CMake to also put header files into your XCode project, you simply need to add the corresponding header files to your sources.

In your case, you should also add `xxx1.hpp` and `inner/in_xxx1.hpp` as parameters of `add_executables`. So far, I have not seen any disadvantage of that.